# Unable to transform an sf object to an sp object due to error with unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sf, r-sp

I am currently working on a sf dataset of points in R, and I want to transform that dataset to an SpatialPointsDataFrame for some downstream analysis. This seems easy enough so I use the `as_Spatial()` function, but it throws an error that I've never seen before:

`Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt) : unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)`

The object I'm trying to transform is a little large for me to add to the question, but the basic object information is as follows:

```
Simple feature collection with 1357 features and 10 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 2.763816 ymin: 4.292756 xmax: 13.66089 ymax: 13.76644
geographic CRS: WGS 84
```

I tried to transform the CRS code of the object, thinking it might have a string that the as_Spatial function isn't recognizing. But when I tried to use the `st_transform()` function, it doesn't look like it updated the geographic CRS. I guess one workaround is change my workflow upstream so that I don't use sf objects, but that would mean throwing away a lot of prior work and use the less efficient `intersect()` function instead of the `st_join()` function. If anyone has any idea where I can look to troubleshoot this issue, that would be fantastic. Thank you all.

Comment: Have a look here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372692/how-should-i-handle-crs-properly-after-the-major-change-in-proj-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little more digging and it looked like the CRS for the `sf` object was incorrectly set. For some reason when I loaded in the initial shapefile prior to my spatial join, the CRS incorporated a ton of extra information that `sf` ended up not able to handle. I used `st_crs()` to reset the CRS information and that resolved the issue.